Filters and 404 header response - correct way?
I have a filter page and some filter combinations may exclude all products or content. Search engines (especially Google) index these pages well and find a huge number of these empty content filter pages.
Question: is it correct for these pages (without products) to return a 404 error or what do I need to do with these pages to disable indexing, but so that when the content appears, Google returns to this URL.


You didn’t specify the technology you’re using, but generally, when a search in a database yields no results, it’s better to return a 200 OK
status with a user-friendly message instead of a 404 error. This way, the page remains indexable, and you can add a  tag to prevent indexing of empty pages. This allows Google to return when content becomes available.

About what tag we are talking about? What tag I should add for correct indexing only if page have content?
